# What i am doing wrong when calculate scene bounding sphere in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box

I am trying to fit the scene in to view. 
I write function to compute scene bounding sphere and then change camera distance to fit it … and see nothing. I just can't find out where I am wrong.

```
  @getRadius = (model, distance)=>
    if typeof model.geometry != "undefined"
      model.updateMatrixWorld true
      model.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true
      model.geometry.computeBoundingSphere true
      sphere = model.geometry.boundingSphere
      distance = Math.max(model.position.distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))+sphere.center.distanceTo(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))+sphere.radius, distance)
    for element in model.children
      distance = Math.max(@getRadius(element, distance), distance)
    return distance

  @fitToView = (model)=>
    radius = @getRadius @scene, 0, 0
    @camera.position.z = radius/Math.tan((22.5*Math.PI)/180)
    @camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

Model is loaded correctly and showing … before I try to "fit it to the View".
You may see example here: http://dresser.websaints.net/wig/preview/5/
Help me find out what I am doing wrong.

With all best regards. Anton.

P.S. and yes, I definitely google this and use stackoverflow search. And read all this topics. I know how to do it. Problem is I can't find out why it don't work like it should.

Comment: Your link only reports an error

Comment: sorry, I experimenting and id of the model have changed
http://dresser.websaints.net/wig/preview/5/ will do

Comment: You don't have anything to render, I am not sure why. In your scene, you have only the light, nothing else. I have seen an attempt to load a collada file, and it reports no errors, but looks like it isn't succesful. May be you don't attach it to the scene ?

Comment: hm strange, at the moment all loading right http://dresser.websaints.net/wig/preview/6/ for example

Comment: I change code a little. now you may see the wig, but it much smaller the it should. Can't figure out why.

Comment: hm … if @camera.position.z = radius/Math.tan((45*Math.PI)/180) it look kind of OK. Thank you all.